# Creating plan in O365 programatically with MS Graph API

Tags: c#, office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I’m trying to create a plan in O365 by code with VS 2015 and the MS Graph Api.
In order to do this, I need to create a group first – no problem here, i can easiely create a new group. Then, I add a user to the group. I simply get the ”me”-user from the Graph API and add it to the group. So far so good.
Now comes the tricky part: Creating the plan.
This fails with a `"The request is invalid."`.
The HttpRequestMessage fires against the url „https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/plans”, with the pa-rameters `{"owner":"628c8e65-fbf4-4558-985a-315152e684bd","title":"Create new workspace"}`.
Creating the plan randomly fails, sometimes the request is successful, but most of the time it fails with the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "The request is invalid.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "0e5ce236-51c6-487f-b0d8-e35e1d45ecae",
      "date": "2016-11-02T09:29:04"
    }
  }
}
```

If I use the same call in the tester “https://graph.microsoft.io/de-de/graph-explorer#” everything seems fine.

I assumed a time-problem, so I added a `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, which seems to help in some cases, but most of the time it doesn’t. Also since this code is supposed to be part of a product, slowing it down artificially isn’t really an option.

Can someone please suggest where I should start looking for a solution?

Edit: I just realised, that the plan is indeed created, but nevertheless the API returns `"The request is invalid."`. So, the plan is created - nice. But without the response I have no way of getting the id of the plan, which I need later on in the code. Any suggestions here?